# add local rss feed into live bookmark

Tags: firefox, rss, rss2

i have a website which i want to monitor, and i have create a script that convert information i need in that website into a rss feed file. i want firefox to add this file as live bookmark. when type the location of the rss feed file, firefox does not display as usual rss feed. how to make firefox display it as i want ? sorry for my bad english.

update: after googling, i wonder if it's due to content-type header ? but i don't know how to set content-type of local file in firefox-addons :-(

Comment: Could it be that the feed you create is not valid?

Comment: nope, i have try to upload to my web server and it's okay.